# My divs become unaligned in smaller resolutions?

Tags: html, css, position

Using only HTML and CSS.

So i have a large background image that I drew. 
I don't want an ugly horizontal scroll bar so
I set the bg image width to: 100%;

I've used percents on EVERYTHING even font size.
However, no matter what I do the text runs off the page on smaller resolutions.

When the resolution is smaller, the background image is also smaller thus the div is becoming unaligned to the background??

I cant get it to look centered and not run off the screen in smaller resolutions.

Please explain what I am doing wrong and what is the solution.

Here is the basic code so far:

```
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/Kl5fDHa.png" class="dead" style="position: fixed;">

<img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img924/5227/cxz6vT.png" id="vacant" style="position: absolute;">



<style>

#vacant {
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto; }

.dead {
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%; }

body { 
background: #071b41; }

.blink {
top: 166%;
left: 38%;
color: #66799b;
font-family: Times New Roman;
font-size: 80%;
height: 3620px;
overflow: hidden; }

</style>

<div class="blink" style="position: absolute;">
<center>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <br>
consectetur adipiscing elit. <br><br>

Fusce venenatis tortor at diam tempus, <br>
at gravida arcu placerat. <br>
Donec varius placerat justo in consequat. <br>
Ut hendrerit tellus id ultrices tincidunt. <br><br>
```

( text continues down the center of the screen )
but runs off the bottom on the smaller resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is a trivial and simple problem to solve. All you have to do is remove the `position: absolute;` property from your `div` with the class of `blink` (`<div class="blink"><!--...--></div>`).

---

Here is a <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ob0dbd1y/)</kbd>.

Comment: But without the position absolute the text stays at the top of the page instead of where the top: 166%; position is. and i forgot to mention the host im using has coding filters and i cannot put the position attribute in my style tags.

Comment: Try using `margin` tags, or the `margin-top` tag.

Comment: yeah ive tried that too. no matter what the text still runs off the page, forcing me to have to resize the font smaller in order for it not to. but then the font becomes too small for my regular resolution.